# Filebeat is sending only data to logstash when it get restart for 2mins and then stop

Tags: filebeat

Filebeat not sending data continuously to kibana

Tried updating filebeat.yml and restarting filebeat but only send data at that moment I restart and stop , but the logs on server are updating continuously.

Filebeat-kafka-logstash-kibana

Comment: Can you please share some logs and filebeat.yml configurations? Without more information, it is not possible to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: May you please add some clarity in addition to logs. It sounds like FIlebeat is able to send some logs successfully, but then restarts. And then after the restart Filebeat is not able to send logs??